# why PDO crashes if initialized in another php file?

Tags: pdo, null, prepared-statement, call, member

I have this PDO object called "dbv". I initialize it in my config.php included file. It gives the error:

> "Fatal error : Call to a member function prepare() on null".

After a few refreshes, it also said:

> "Notice: Undefined variable: dbv"

But it would not say something like

> "failed to open stream config.php"

If I cut all inside the config.php file and paste it directly above my `$dbv->prepare()` `function`, inside `drawHeader()` from **sections.php**, it works fine.

How can I make it work initializing my PDO inside config.php?

I have 3 files:

php/config.php (where I initialize the PDO)

php/sections.php (where I have my drawHeader() with the pdo->prepare() function that fails)

main.php (my main page that I open in the browser)

Here is my code:

**config.php:**

```
<?php
    $database="dbname";
    $username="dbuser";
    $password="dbpass";

    $dbv=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;port=3308;dbname=".$database,$username,$password);
?>
```

**sections.php:**

```
<?php

function drawHeader() {

if (!isset($_SESSION["LIMBA"])) {
    $_SESSION["LIMBA"]="ro";
}

$limba=$_SESSION["LIMBA"];

echo '
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="'.$limba.'">

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Condensed:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylesheet.css">
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <title>My title</title>';
        


$query="SELECT * FROM pagini_statice WHERE URL=?";
$stmt=$dbv->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindValue(1, $_SESSION['URL']);;    
$stmt->execute();
$pag=$stmt->fetch();
echo $pag["CSS"];

//the rest of the code .....
```

**main.php:**

```
<?php
include("php/config.php");
include_once("php/sections.php");
session_start();
$_SESSION["URL"]="pagina.php";

drawHeader();

drawFooter();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `require`/`include` the config.php file, like:

```
<?php

require_once 'your/path/to/config.php';

function drawHeader() {

if (!isset($_SESSION["LIMBA"])) {
    $_SESSION["LIMBA"]="ro";
}

$limba=$_SESSION["LIMBA"];

echo '
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="'.$limba.'">

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Condensed:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylesheet.css">
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <title>My title</title>';
        


$query="SELECT * FROM pagini_statice WHERE URL=?";
$stmt=$dbv->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindValue(1, $_SESSION['URL']);;    
$stmt->execute();
$pag=$stmt->fetch();
echo $pag["CSS"];
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work.. the mainpage.php is in the root folder, and config.php and sections.php are in the php folder, so in sections.php I wrote require_once 'config.php'; Is that right? (the php folder is in the root folder)

Comment: @dutu000 please share the relevant part of your folder structure, I only know what you described above. Also, please tell me what the URL you are loading is. Thanks!

Comment: It seems not to be able to use $dbv inside functions (they don't see it as a global variable), but if I put it as an argument like header($dbv) when I call it and header($pdo) when I declare it , and do $pdo->prepare inside the function, it works... Why can't I just use $dbv inside functions?

Comment: @dutu000 I see. Does it work as `$GLOBALS['dbv']` inside the function?